# State of calling activity after startActivityForResult and Home key is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

I have a launcher Activity called `HomeActivity`.

And a `LoginActivity` from where the user has to login to access the other screens.

`HomeActivity` is marked as `singleTask`.

In HomeActivity's `onCreate()` method, I launch the `LoginActivity` if the user is not logged in.

And in `LoginActivity`, I just call a `finish()`, to dismiss the `LoginActivity`, assuming that the `HomeActivity` is the next activity in the stack to be shown.

This setup works for most of the cases, except one.

1. User is not logged in.
2. Launch app -> Launches `HomeActivity`
3. No login detected -> Launches `LoginActivity`
4. On `LoginActivity`, press home.
5. Launch the app, and I see the `LoginActivity`.
6. Do a login, and on success, `LoginActivity` is finished.

Instead of seeing the `HomeActivity`, I see the HomeScreen. Is that expected? Am I doing anything wrong?

I don't have the developer option **"Don't keep activities"** turned **off**. So, was wondering how the activity stack loses the `HomeActivity`, since I am expecting the `HomeActivity` to be the next Activity to come up after I finish the `LoginActivity`.

**Cancel or Login methods in LoginActivity:**

```
public void doLogin(View v) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
}

public void cancel(View v) {
       setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
       finish();
}
```

**Calling LoginActivity:**

Called from `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`.

**Why onNewIntent() is needed?** So that, from anywhere else, I can just start the `HomeActivity`, and `onNewIntent()` would be called, in case of session expiry. All the other activities on top of `HomeActivity` would be removed, and `LoginActivity` should be shown.

```
protected void onCreated(Bundle savedInstance){
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
             startLoginActivity();
        }
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
             startLoginActivity();
        }
}

private void startLoginActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}
```

**On Activity Result of HomeActivity:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                finish();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**The manifest file:**

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name="com.example.checkact.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.checkact.LoginActivity"></activity>
```

**Update:** Using `singleTop` seems to work fine, but I have no idea why does it behave like this with `singleTask`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's off.

Answer (score -1):

I would not stack the activities for this.

If you need to launch the Log In Activity, start the activity and call finish() in your HomeActivity.

```
if(!loggedIn){
    Intent logInActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    //Potentially display a toast to say why the user is being directed to the log in screen
    // add bundle into that flags to Go back to main activity. 
   logInActivity.put extra("activity", 1);
    startActivity(logInActivity);
    finish();
}
```

Similar with the Log-In Activity, after you successfully authenticate, call the following:

```
if(loggedIn){
    // get bundle it 
      Int a = get intent.getExtras().getInt("activity");
     if(a==1)
    Intent next= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    ///have a code for each activity that you could resume to
    startActivity(next);
    finish();
}
```

This should alleviate your state issues.

Comment: That would probably not work in my situation. I have different activities that can launch the LoginActivity, if any of them detect that the user's session has expired.

Comment: If you use bundles you can track the state of your app. See my edit - I wrote this on my commute, so syntaxically not perfect!

Comment: Yep, I could do that, but it would probably not be an ideal solution. For now, may be I can use that, but I want to understand why the app behaves this way.

Comment: This might help with your understanding ....http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1874864